# Custom namespace for mypy invocation

Tags: python, mypy

I want to use mypy to typecheck a python script. This script depends on global variables that are set via `exec` when the script is called.

Is there a way to invoke mypy with a dictionary of variables similar to `exec` so my script can be type checked? If this is not possible what are the alternative approaches?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly tell mypy which variables exist in the source code:

```
MY_EXTRA_VAR: int

print("result", MY_EXTRA_VAR + 10)
```

Now mypy won't complain. But you can also get rid of the calling magic like this:

```
def run(my_extra_var: int):
    print("result", my_extra_var + 10)
```

Then you have to change your calling script to import the module (maybe dynamically) and run the `run` function.